# Break point not hitting in sharepoint 2010 project

Tags: solution

Breakpoints in my solution are  not hitting.I have reset the iis and the timer services as well but nothing works.If anyone could help me it would be great.

Comment: Make sure the build is set to Debug and not Release

Comment: Which kind of project? Web parts, event receivers, timer jobs?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a time-out/load problem.
Try reducing the  number of simultaneously open Visual Studio SharePoint projects / assemblies that will be debugged in your Visual Studio solution to one or very few. VS tries to load the debug symbols for all open projects.